# Why do things want to lower their energy?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy

Like if we consider a container of gas molecules as a system, Why does it want to lower its energy?

I have read that always more spontaneous events are favored. So Gibb's Free energy should have a negative value i.e ΔG=ΔH-TΔS<0. So Entropy Contributes towards more spontaneity. But Randomness contributes towards more entropy and having more Internal energy causes more random motion.
So overall more energy should contribute towards more Spontaneity which is favored in nature. But we observe that things tend to lower their energy. Please Explain.

Edit: Well I guess I might have found the answer - 
When a system lowers its energy, ΔH becomes negative ( due to it being exothermic) so at moderate temperatures, the entropy contributes to lower spontaneity but ΔH is more negative so ΔG becomes more negative(more spontaneous). While at high temperatures, endothermic processes are favored (ΔH positive)
Thermodynamics is so beautiful!

Comment: It is quite difficult to answer such a question. First no physical system want something. It does. Also associating randomness to entropy is a difficult exercise. Something moving faster is not more disordered, just think of fixed frame shots. While the answer by Maurice deserve downvotes - one is mine - it is true that what we observe lead us to conclusion. Thermodynamics goes this way. In this respect it is correct that you won't be much surprised to listen that heat (energy flow) goes from a warmer to a colder body, or that a body in a gravity field falls to lower its potential E.

Comment: I hope someone has the skill and patience to help you getting the right track

Comment: We have discovered a property of something we call matter which we call energy, and that follows the rules that it does. Beyond that lies philosophy.

Comment: This is one of those questions that will take you to the frontiers of physics and out into the unknown in short order. Basically, it is because on a macroscopic scale time has a direction. As to why...

Comment: They don't want to, they are forced to.  The Universe wants to raise its entropy, which requires extracting heat from things, which lowers the energy of said things.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe my shortest answer ever:

Energy is *loosely* a measure of how disturbed a system it is from its natural, grounded, non-excited state, and it is from here that the "less energy, more stable" thing comes from. Your question reverse-engineers that.

Answer (score -3):

It is an observation coming from the study of the gravitation. If you allow an object situated on a table to move somewhat, it may happen that the object is at the edge of the table, and fall to the ground. The contrary never happens spontaneously.